# Send message from one program to another in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two different executable files running on same computer which has Windows OS. Both of them are build in Unity. I want to send message from one to other **without using network**.

How do you send message from an exe program to another exe program in Unity?

Is this possible with `integrated Mono/.net functionality` or something else?

Comment: Ramdisk is fast

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use *Named Pipes* which uses shared memory to communicate with another application on **the-same** machine.

Go to *File* --> *Build Settings...* select *PC, Mac & Linux Standalone* then click on *Player Settings...*. Now, change *Api Compatibility Level* to *.NET 2.0*.

Close and re-open Visual Studio. Now, you can import `using System.IO.Pipes;` and be able to use `NamedPipeServerStream` and `NamedPipeClientStream`.

Below is a very *simplified* server and client. You **must** do that in a `Thread` and should also handle exception.

If you don't want to use `Thread`, there is also asynchronous parameter (`PipeOptions.Asynchronous`) that makes it a non blocking operator. It gets complicated from there and you have to look for some examples for that on MS doc.

**Simple Server**:

```
//Create Server Instance
NamedPipeServerStream server = new NamedPipeServerStream("MyCOMApp", PipeDirection.InOut, 1);
//Wait for a client to connect
server.WaitForConnection();
//Created stream for reading and writing
StreamString serverStream = new StreamString(server);
//Send Message to Client
serverStream.WriteString("Hello From Server");
//Read from Client
string dataFromClient = serverStream.ReadString();
UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Received from Client: " + dataFromClient);
//Close Connection
server.Close();
```

**Simple Client**:

```
//Create Client Instance
NamedPipeClientStream client = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "MyCOMApp",
               PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.None,
               TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation);

//Connect to server
client.Connect();
//Created stream for reading and writing
StreamString clientStream = new StreamString(client);
//Read from Server
string dataFromServer = clientStream.ReadString();
UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Received from Server: " + dataFromServer);
//Send Message to Server
clientStream.WriteString("Bye from client");
//Close client
client.Close();
```

The `StreamString` class from [MS Doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public class StreamString
{
    private Stream ioStream;
    private UnicodeEncoding streamEncoding;

    public StreamString(Stream ioStream)
    {
        this.ioStream = ioStream;
        streamEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
    }

    public string ReadString()
    {
        int len = 0;

        len = ioStream.ReadByte() * 256;
        len += ioStream.ReadByte();
        byte[] inBuffer = new byte[len];
        ioStream.Read(inBuffer, 0, len);

        return streamEncoding.GetString(inBuffer);
    }

    public int WriteString(string outString)
    {
        byte[] outBuffer = streamEncoding.GetBytes(outString);
        int len = outBuffer.Length;
        if (len > UInt16.MaxValue)
        {
            len = (int)UInt16.MaxValue;
        }
        ioStream.WriteByte((byte)(len / 256));
        ioStream.WriteByte((byte)(len & 255));
        ioStream.Write(outBuffer, 0, len);
        ioStream.Flush();

        return outBuffer.Length + 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the solution I was looking for

Comment: I implemented the code you provided. But it throws this error :                                 
NotImplementedException: ACL is not supported in Mono
I searched for a solution but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: You are running this on windows, right? Please start commenting from bottom to up to see which line of code is causing that error.

Comment: Yes. It is running on Windows 8.1. It throws the error in the beginning when it creates new NamedPipeClientStream.

Comment: `NamedPipeServerStream`  must be running before you can use `NamedPipeClientStream`. Can you run it as an admin and see what happens?

Comment: So this works in Unity now? For a while people were saying that named pipes caused a crash.

Comment: `Cannot resolve symbol 'StreamString'` I got this error in my case. Any ideas why? I included using System.IO;

Answer (score 1):

You could have a file they both write and read to.
You can put a timestamp with it to show when the last message was written

Comment: True @Programmer You could use like a database which you add rows with a message column to but that is quite a lot of work for a very little thing

Comment: Year. Any database that uses RAM for storage should do it. I think there are few out there. Although, that's like drink water with a bucket.

Comment: I don't think your answer is very useful as it stands now. I think you at least need to mention the problems that might occur with this solution. What happens when both applications try to write to the file at the same time for example? Or when one application is still writing and the other already wants to read from the file?

Comment: I thought about this too but this didn't seem like a good solution. But it solves the problem anyway :)

Comment: if you use `File.WriteAllText("path", "message");` you should not have this problem