# How do I embed a Unity exe inside WPF app using .NET Core 3.0

Tags: wpf, unity-game-engine, .net-core-3.0

I'm trying to embed a Unity application inside a WPF uploader as sort of a live 3D viewer for uploading models to a server.

I've found tutorials that show how to to this using WinForms, and how to embed a generic exe in WPF using standard .NET framework. I've spent a lot of time trying to upgrade those projects to work with .NET Core 3.0 WPF, but with little success.

My main issue is that while things like notepad.exe are being embedded, the Unity app creates its own separate window. I feel like there is some minor thing I'm overlooking, but can't figure out what. I have limited experience with .NET and WPF, so any pointers are appreciated.

These are the tutorials I followed:

EXE in WPF
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/673701/Hosting-EXE-Applications-in-a-WPF-Window-Applicati

Unity in WinForms
[Embed Unity3D app inside WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44059182/embed-unity3d-app-inside-wpf-application/44059700)

As I explained, I want to implement the embedded window in a WPF app and not WinForms which is linked above, since I already have the rest of the uploader built with WPF using .NET Core 3.0. I would essentially like to have a separate container within the existing app to run my Unity instance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embed Unity3D app inside WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44059182/embed-unity3d-app-inside-wpf-application)

Comment: The linked post implements this in WinForm, which I have linked to in my original question. I've updated the question to clarify further.