# How to execute Unity game in WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-game-engine

I am researching Unity (2020.3 editor version) for my project in WPF/C# (MS Visual Studio 2022 - .NET 7). I have to rotate a material with quaternions given from my WPF project. I don't want a standalone Unity project, My need is to integrate Unity into WPF.

But I don't find a piece of suitable information to integrate and connect Unity and WPF. I don't know if there is a better way to handle this.

Is it possible to use Unity in WPF or maybe it is better to use another desktop/GUI framework like winui3?

Comment: Just because Unity works with C# doesn't mean you can use WPF in it. That is not the point at all. Unity is a standalone engine that can be used in games, movies or architecture and is not related to WPF. There might be some hacks that could probably force some sort of interaction or you could probably use TCP to communicate between Unity and WPF, but as I said, that is not how it's supposed to work. WPF and Unity go together like writing something for Windows and something for Unix. Both use C, so they should work unchanged, correct? Well no :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embed Unity3D app inside WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44059182/embed-unity3d-app-inside-wpf-application)