# How to link WinForms app button to Unity game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have Unity game and i need to make control panel for it. I think it should look like this: [my bad drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5PPw.png.) anyone have ideas how to make this?

Comment: Why do you need WinForm for your game? What is wrong with the Unity UI?

Comment: Have a look at `named pipes`.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062782/send-message-from-one-program-to-another-in-unity) is another question doing what you are asking.

Comment: Looks like thats thing i wanted to do, thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send message from one program to another in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43062782/send-message-from-one-program-to-another-in-unity)